# Laravel 5.5 Queue: No connector for []

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two websites running identical laravel 5.5 project. In fact both websites hosted on the same server. One of them works, another one has troubles with queues. I have double-checked everything. 
`.env`:

```
...
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
...
```

conf/queue.php

```
'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
```

I do have empty `jobs` table as well.
Whenever I do try to run queues I'm getting an error

```
php artisan queue:work --daemon

In QueueManager.php line 172:

  No connector for []
```

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: i do believe `php artisan config:cache` may help, but i dont remember exactly what I did

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I have an app that was working fine and all of a sudden I'm getting this error on all my queues.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the config queue drive setting. If use Redis, you can use `php artisan tinker` check
current the config.
Check command queue:

`php artisan queue:work redis --queue=QUEUE_NAME --tries=3 --memory=128 --timeout=300`

Check job listen by command line:
 `ps aux | grep php`

Comment: I wish I can reproduce the error again. But 2 and half year have passed. Hopefully someone can have input on that if this helped

Answer (score 1):

I just had to specify a "connection" (`database` for my case) after `queue:work` command like below:

```
php artisan queue:work database --queue=Q_NAME
```

and the error disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I encountered the same problem and couldn't find the solution but I followed laravel deploy optimizations, like cache config, view and routes which result into this. (I am not sure why).
I followed these and it worked like magic. (I don't know why it worked)

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: To clarify, by same problem do you mean the same version of Laravel and the same exact error message including line number?

Comment: Mine is 7, same exact message yes and similar situation though it was working before I did the things, I mentioned.